# how to segment groups based on different criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, testing, case-when, ab-testing

I'm trying to assign test and control groups based on A to F columns values to the table below.

[image]

Eventually, I want a table look like below. If different zips have the same values for all columns, then assign half zips to test and half to control. If the total number of zips cannot be equally assigned, then give the extra zip to control.

[image]

Comment: Your definition of what to do with the groups with odd numbers will result in a biased control group, because all the onesies will end up in that group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a stratified sample will do what you want:

```
select t.*,
       (case when mod(row_number() over (order by a, b, c, d, e, f), 2) = 1
             then 'C' else 'T'
        end) as test_group
from t;
```

This is not *exactly* how you phrased the question, but it should have the same effect of splitting rows with the same values in the columns evenly in the two groups.  When there are odd numbers, sometimes the extra will go to test and sometimes to control.

It is unclear from the question whether you want balanced control and test groups -- which is what I would expect.  If you actually want all groups with odd numbers to go to control (as you suggest), then all the onesies will be in the control and that seems biased to me.

Comment: this is great, thank you! It doesn't matter the odd number goes to test or control, so this is exactly what i need!

Comment: @Lion . . . Your question is phrased differently, which is why I elaborate so much in this answer.  My guess is that a stratified sample is exactly what you want.  It is generally the best approach for splitting data into two statistically similar groups.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `row_number()` and `mod()`:

```
select 
    t.*,
    case when mod(
        row_number() over(partition by A, B, C, D, E, F order by zip), 
        2
    ) = 0 then 'T' else 'C' end tc_group
from mytable t
```

`row_number()` assigns increasing numbers to records that share the same `(A, B, C, D, E, F)` values, ordered by increasing `zip`. We would assign even row numbers to testing group `T`, and uneven numbers to group `C`.